# How to heat proof aluminium windows, prevent heat from entering?

Tags: insulation, windows

Aluminium windows made about 15 years ago. In hot climate, all day sun the frame becomes hot to touch when touched from inside. 
What can I do to insulate heat form entering?

- I know about accordion shades to keep/buffer the warm air.
- I know that I can tint the glass with sun protective/dark film.

Are there any solutions to maybe cover the aluminium frame on the outside to prevent it from heating and transmitting the heat to the inside?

Answer (score 1):

There is not a lot you can do here, to be honest, short of replacing the windows with ones better suited for your climate. Painting or covering the exterior with something of any color other than brilliant white may make things worse since shiny aluminum is reflective and is already rejecting some of the heat, and such coatings may not last.

Planting some shade trees or installing awnings to block the sun may be easier, cheaper, more effective alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a sacrificial frame to cover the aluminium one from the outside.  You could even use some white (to reflect the light) uPVC and adhere it to the aluminium.